# Click trigger on page load (UL > LI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, html-lists

I have the following HTML code in my website:

```html
<div id="gallery">
    <ul class="pictures">
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".web">Web</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".design">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".video">Video</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I want to have a click event triggering when the page loads.
I want the first (or second) list item to be clicked when the page loads.

I've tried with the following code, but I failed and I don't know how to do it:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("ul.pictures li:nth-child(2)").trigger("click");
    },10);
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to trigger a jQuery event handler or a native click? Why do you need to trigger a click on pageload?

Comment: I'm new with jQuery/JS.
I, basically, need an item list to be clicked when the website loads.
Because my gallery is divided into filters.

Comment: Why not give a default value to the properties your click event targets? Set these values to be the same as clicking on the first or second list item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Problem

The code is triggering the "onclick" event on the li element. You want to trigger the "onclick" event on the "a" element.

### Solution

```
$('#gallery li:nth-child(2) a').click();
```

### Example

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3bXw/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If  you are perfoming click action on  Li tag , then  below code will be helpfull.

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul class="pictures">
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".web">Web</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".design">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".video">Video</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
  setTimeout(function () {
                $('.pictures li:nth-child(1)').trigger("click");
            }, 10);
```