# How to make jQuery click a random li element on page load?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to trigger a .click handler on a random team of my list.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sidebar li:nth-child() a').click();
});
```

Also tried:

[Click trigger on page load (UL > LI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130984/click-trigger-on-page-load-ul-li) 
[Auto-click button element on page load using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646881/auto-click-button-element-on-page-load-using-jquery)

```
        <li class="countries" id="2"><img src="{% static "images/england.png" %}" alt="england">Premier League
          <ul class="subbar">
            <li><a class="team" id="12">FC Liverpool</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="13">Manchester City</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="17">Tottenham Hotspur</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="14">Manchester United</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="11">Leicester City</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="6">FC Chelsea</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="2">FC Arsenal</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="1">AFC Bournemouth</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="19">West Ham United</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="16">FC Southapmton</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="8">FC Everton</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="7">Crystal Palace</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="5">Cardiff City</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="4">FC Burnley</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="9">Fulham</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="3">Brighton & Hove Albion</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="15">Newcastle United</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="10">Huddersfield Town</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="20">Wolverhampton Wand.</a></li>
            <li><a class="team" id="18">FC Watford</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: Try using [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: Ok, but it is not taking any action at all, hmh

Comment: Instead of `.click()` you should use `.trigger("click")`  But that isn't going to work, as the selector won't return any valid items. You need to generate a random value based on the number `li` items, create a selector string using that random value, and then trigger on that result

Comment: Like so? ```randomID = function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(0);
  max = Math.floor(20);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(''#randomID'').trigger('click');
});```

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I start, I should say that having a number as an `id` attribute is invalid in HTML.  You can fix it by simply putting any characters before hand, for example `id="a1"`.

You should use [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) to generate a random value, based on the number of `li` items in your list.

You can create a new selector by placing that random value in the `nth-child` part....

(Note, I originally said that instead of using `.click()` the OP should use `.trigger("click")`.  That was wrong, and the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/click/) clearly show that `.click()` is valid and simply a shortcut for `.trigger("click")`.)

```js
$(function(){
  $("a.team").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this)[0].id + " - " + $(this)[0].innerHTML);
  });
  
  var numLi = $(".subbar li").length;
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(numLi)) + 1;
  $(".subbar li:nth-child(" + rnd.toString() + ") a").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="subbar">
  <li><a class="team" id="12">FC Liverpool</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="13">Manchester City</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="17">Tottenham Hotspur</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="14">Manchester United</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="11">Leicester City</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="6">FC Chelsea</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="2">FC Arsenal</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="1">AFC Bournemouth</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="19">West Ham United</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="16">FC Southapmton</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="8">FC Everton</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="7">Crystal Palace</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="5">Cardiff City</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="4">FC Burnley</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="9">Fulham</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="3">Brighton & Hove Albion</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="15">Newcastle United</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="10">Huddersfield Town</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="20">Wolverhampton Wand.</a></li>
  <li><a class="team" id="18">FC Watford</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: rnd number generates smoothly, but there still is no trigger action going on. I don't get any errors either when debugging. Fixed it, lol someone slap me. Thanks mate

Comment: I've just updated my answer, as I was wrong about the `.click()`... it **should** work, if it doesn't, then there is something else wrong in your code which is impossible for me to know about